# good reference for the Laplace method

Tags: real-analysis

I was wondering if someone could suggest good reference about the Laplace method.

One source I have now is just a short section (appendix) of Stein's Complex Analysis textbook.

I wish it starts with basic materials and provide rather precise error bounds, and also treats multidimensional case.

Thank you very much.

Comment: It should be mentioned which type of Laplace methods do you want. I know Laplace method is a technique to solve differential equations. I did not think that you were asking different.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Don't be sorry. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bender & Orszag](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387989315), Ch. 6, esp. Sec. 6.4, has a terrific treatment, ripe with detailed examples, error analysis, but at a level in which anyone with a decent background in calculus can be an expert.

Comment: This book is good, but do you happen to know a text which treats Laplace method for complex values of x going to infinity? Also it doesn't seem to treat multidimensional case.

Comment: @a12345: I didn't know that's what you wanted.  In that case, I can recommend Bleistein & Handelman, *Asymptotic Expansion of Integrals*, esp. Ch. 8.  http://www.amazon.com/Asymptotic-Expansions-Integrals-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486650820

Answer (score 1):

[Wong, Asymptotic Approximation of Integrals](https://books.google.de/books?id=EpHiBQAAQBAJ) is a widely cited reference for the Laplace method. The last chapter includes a section on the application of the method to integrals in $\mathbb{R}^N$.